# I am trying to iterate over ArrayType of Structs, how can I do that? I see there are no specific functions in class ArrayType to do this

Tags: pyspark

This is the snippet:

ArrayType(
StructType(
[
StructField(“EmpID”, StringType(), True),
StructField(
“EmpAdd”,
StructType(
[
StructField(“HouseNo”, StringType(), True),
StructField(“City”, StringType(), True),
]
),
True,
),
]
),
True,
)

Expected:

Iterate over this and get all the elements:

StructType(
[
StructField(“EmpID”, StringType(), True),
StructField(
“EmpAdd”,
StructType(
[
StructField(“HouseNo”, StringType(), True),
StructField(“City”, StringType(), True),
]
),
True,
),
]
),
True,

I dont find any method to iterate over this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to get the 0th element of the above Array